# xlC compiling error on using Boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using multiprecision from Boost library. On compiling my program, I'm getting error `"boost_1_68_0/boost/atomic/detail/int_sizes.hpp", line 107.47: CCN5830 (S) The suffix of the integer literal "0xffffffffffffffffui64" is not valid."`

Program is complied in AIX using below command:-

```
xlC -O2 -I<BOOST PATH>/boost_1_68_0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_ALL_SOURCE -qLANGLVL=EXTENDED -qLANGLVL=EXTENDED0X -qFLOAT=IEEE -qSUPPRESS=CCN5122 -qSUPPRESS=CCN5700 -qSUPPRESS=CCN5816 -c boost_multiprecision.cpp
```

Comment: xlc is not a supported compiler for Boost: https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_68_0.html Not very surprising that there are some gaps in the support.

Comment: Try `0xffffffffffffffffull` instead.

Comment: Indeed, you will have to change some things like that by hand.